# Dell OpenManage Server Administrator: download link?

Tags: dell, dell-openmanage

Not installed on the server I'm remotely managing at the moment (Windows SBS 2008 R2).

I can only find links to the manual in the Support Downloads section at dell.com.

Easy points up for grabs (hopefully).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This should do the trick.](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails?driverId=NVRR4) (Updated for version 7.2.0 A01 released 1/11/2013.)

Comment: Awesome, must've overlooked that.

Comment: For future reference, it's available in the driver downloads for a server in the System Management section.

Comment: Also note that version is out of date now as a new version was released in March (click link above, then Other Versions, then the newer one), or for now [this is correct](http://support.dell.com/support/downloads/download.aspx?c=us&cs=04&l=en&s=bsd&releaseid=R300521&SystemID=PWE_R710&servicetag=&os=WS8R2&osl=en&deviceid=2331&devlib=0&typecnt=0&vercnt=4&catid=-1&impid=-1&formatcnt=0&libid=36&typeid=-1&dateid=-1&formatid=-1&source=-1&fileid=451207]).

Comment: Just to provide an update (it was still hard to find on the Dell site and I ended up back here again!), [Version 7.1.0 was released on 7/2/2012, click here to download.](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/555/DriverDetails?driverId=30T1C&fileId=2962652778)

Comment: [Version 7.2.0 A01](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/04/DriverDetails?driverId=NVRR4) is out now as of Jan 11, 2013.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the filename you want to download, in your case it would be OM-SrvAdmin-Dell-Web-WIN-6.5.0-2124_A00.22.exe, then all the files are available in ftp.dell.com/sysman/

For help with the naming conventions have a look at http://ftp.dell.com/sysman/New%20file%20naming%20convention%20for%20OMSA,%20ITA,%20DRAC%20and%20BMC%20software%20releases.docx